# A word for "something that can be rolled-back"

Tags: single-word-requests

Supposing I have a given operation/sequence of operations that can be either commited or rolled-back, can I say that each operation is "rollbackable"? What is a word for something that can be rolled back?

Comment: Any particular reason not to use *reversible* or one of its synonyms?

Comment: We're trying to make something analog to the process of "rollback" on a relational database, hence the preference for something that cleary says "rollback".

Comment: it's reversible.

Comment: rollbackable seems fine - go for it

Comment: If your preference is to clearly say that something can be rolled back, then your best option is to clearly say that it can be rolled back. Bending over backwards to create a new word, as morphologically sound as it might be, is clearly not the clearest way. You just said, it can be either commited or rolled back. I am not seeing any kind of problem with that. Now you want to instead say it's committable and rollbackable. I have to ask you to elaborate on why you would want any such thing.

Comment: Maybe it's _restorable_ or _reestablishable_.

Comment: Also, I would like to raise the point of whether you can roll back something that hasn't been committed yet. If you haven't committed the sequence of actions, then they have not taken any effect yet. And so you can cancel them, or discard them, or dismiss them, but there is simply nothing to roll back.

Comment: [Backtrackable](http://xsb.sourceforge.net/shadow_site/manual1/node91.html)?

Comment: The object obviously has versioning.

Answer (score 0):

A fine word that exists is:

***Repealable***

> repeal (v.) late 14c., from Anglo-French repeler, Old French rapeler "call back, call in, call after, revoke" (Modern French rappeler), from re- "back" (see re-) + apeler "to call" (see appeal (v.)). Related: Repealed; repealing.

It's unambiguous and not used in Database circles; its only failing is that is refers to "calls" which have little to do with this particular problem domain.

How about a cross-lingual portmanteau: From the German word "rear", `rück` combined with *roll*, I get:

***Ruckrollable***

You can add the Umlaut to make it look exotic. It has the dubious features of sounding like "rock and roll" and "Rick-rolling". Or Scooby-Doo.

Comment: that's quite clever about ruckrollable